# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'products' of undefined in Angular 6, problem with model

Tags: angular, typescript

I have problem with model.
I have two models `category` and `product`.
Category model is :

```
export class CategoryModel {

public id: number;
public name: string;
public description: string;
public image: string;
public products: ProductModel[] ;


constructor(name: string, desciption: string, image: string = null, products: ProductModel[], id: number) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = desciption;
    this.image = image;
    this.products = products;
}

}
```

product model is :

```
export class ProductModel {
    constructor(

        public id:number,  public name: string, public description: string, public numberOfProduct: number, public image: string) {
    }
}
```

I store date in the `productArray: ProductModel[] = [];` from the server with this method:

```
 getCategory() {
    this.dataStorageServiceService.getCategory().subscribe(category => {
      console.log(category);
      this.categoryList = category;
      console.log(this.categoryList);

    })
  }
```

And I want to store many `products` in the `categoryList` with this method:

```
 storeProduct() {
    let index = 0;

    for (let category of this.categoryList) {
      index++;
      if (category.name == this.productForm.value.category) {
        this.product.name = this.productForm.value.name;
        this.product.image = this.productForm.value.image;
        this.product.description = this.productForm.value.description;

           this.categoryList[index].products.push(this.product);

      }

    }

    this.dataStorageServiceService.storeProduct(this.categoryList[index], index);

  }
```

The product is `product = <ProductModel>{};`
And I have error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'products' of undefined`

Comment: Yeah well of course, you update your index before accessing your array item. So if your array is 10 items, you will try to access the 11th one. See the issue ? Move `index++` to the end of the loop.

Comment: (Also, if you need an index in your loop, why don't you just use a `for` loop instead of a `for ...of` one ?)

Comment: But I have error when  I want to access zero element and in  `product ` I want to add new product with this code : `this.categoryList[0].products.push(new ProductModel(1, '2', '2', 2, 'hshs'))`

Comment: i gave you your error : if it persists, please provide a [mcve] reproducing the issue.

Comment: before add anything.. what is the `this.categoryList`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're trying to do with `index` so I will not try to edit your whole function, but try initializing the objects `this.product` and `this.categoryList[index].products` before interacting with them:

```
this.categoryList[index].products = new Array<ProductModel>();

this.product = new ProductModel();
```

Hope this helps at all.